# Simple form onsubmit not calling javascript function (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've only posted partial javascript code since the complete is a fair bit to much to post all here. But the entire html code can be found [here](http://web.ncf.ca/~eh936/Files/MathJax%20Drag%20and%20Drop.html)

The powerInput() does not get called. I just cannot figure out how to write the code in Jquery. Any help would be great.

```
function someFunction(){

$('#second').append('$${t}^x\\sqrt{t}^x$$');
          $('#container').append('<div id="third" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>');

$('#third').append('<form onsubmit="powerInput()">');

$('#third').append('<span style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 50px;">$${t}\\sqrt{t}$$</span>').css("font-size","200%");

$('#third').append('<input type="text" name="fpower" maxlength="1" style="width: 10px; height:9px; position:absolute; top:27px; left: 60px;">');

$('#third').append('<input type="text" name="spower" maxlength="1" style="width: 10px; height:9px; position:absolute; top: 25px; left:100px;">');   

$('#third').append('<input type="submit">');
$('#third').append('</form>');

}

function powerInput(){ alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Instead of inline handlers, use jQuery's `on()` to bind events. `$('form').on('submit', function() {`.

Comment: The function is Ok. I think the problem is where you are calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending incorrectly, you cannot append part of an html tag into the dom, append the entire code in one string. The way you have it now the form will have no elements in it.

```
$('#third').append('<form onsubmit="powerInput()">' +
    '<span style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 50px;font-size: 200%">$${t}\\sqrt{t}$$</span>' +
    '<input type="text" name="fpower" maxlength="1" style="width: 10px; height:9px; position:absolute; top:27px; left: 60px;">' +
    '<input type="text" name="spower" maxlength="1" style="width: 10px; height:9px; position:absolute; top: 25px; left:100px;">' + 
    '<input type="submit">' +
    '</form>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your script. Press f12 and see if you get any errors in the browser console. There might be some script error

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your all HTML tag in line or inspect element and see whether they add correctly in required div or tag
if they add correctly as you want to add then it run correctly 
because if there error in appending and format it will not execute ahead